# Can I study multivariable calculus without taking a rigorous course in real analysis?

Tags: reference-request, advice

I didn't study in the calculus course(also included multivariable calculus) in my first sem when my college offered it, and now it's cropping up everywhere. Infinite series, fourier transform, probability, even basic equations in physics require vector calculus and multivariable calculus. I am a physics major and I want to go the rigorous route and start from the beginning, but I don't have much time to do it because of my course load.
Is there a way to learn enough mathematics to just afloat in my major until I can do it properly?  I know how to use single variable calculus, though not rigorously. Is there a book or a resource that gives enough math for a physics student but not too simplistic and handwaving?

Comment: Check Hubbard and Hubbard

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: It helps, thank you!